# Passive Voice in sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, passive-voice

> 1-***I don't want my photo taken.***
>
> 2-***I don't want my photo being taken.***
>
> 3-***I don't like my photo being taken.***

As far as I know we can use the (sentences-1,2,3) but why can't we use the following sentences ? Especially while the sentence 1 is okay why the sentence 4 not okay?

> 4-***I don't like my photo taken.***
>
> 5-***I don't like my photo be taken.***

Answer (score 2):

> I don't like to have my photo taken.
>
> I don't like my photo to be taken.

I don't think *I don't like my photo taken* is absolutely ungrammatical. It's in a gray-area. It can be understood as ellipsis of BE:  ... [to be] taken.

Your number 5 is definitely ungrammatical:

> I don't like my photo be taken. <sup>NO</sup>

You need to say **to be** (as in my second sentence above) or use **have**:

> I don't like to have my photo be taken.

Comment: So did we use ellipsis in that sentence "I don't want my photo [to be] taken" .

Comment: @TalhaÖzden:  I understand **taken** there as a complement predicated of the grammatical object **photo** and in that sense there is an implicit BE, but not in the passive sense, not an implicit *be*.

Comment: "Taken" is not predicated of "photo". Such complements are entirely restricted to NPs and AdjPs. "Have" is a catenative verb and "taken" is a non-finite subordinate clause functioning as its catenative complement.

Comment: @BillJ: I don't follow when you say "such complements".  Object complements?

Comment: @BillJ: So, in *She doesn't like to have her hair dyed*, the word **dyed** is not predicated of **hair** in some manner?